# How to write elements of a List of String[] to a csv file in Android

Tags: android, csv, export

I placed an empty file in raw directory called "output.csv". How can I write this list to the file in a structure that list is the whole table and rows are all the String[] elements? In such structure:

```
Column A                 Column B 
List[0],String[0]        List[0].String[1] 
List[1],String[0]        List[1].String[1] 
List[2],String[0]        List[2].String[1] 
. . . and so on.


List<String[]> dataForCSV = new ArrayList<>();
//Consider dataForCSV is filledup
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter (getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("output.csv", 
                        getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE));
     for(String[] data : dataForCSV)
         for(String line : data)
             outputStreamWriter.write(line);
     outputStreamWriter.close();
```

Comment: You cannot write to a file in raw directory as its read only.

Comment: And your code is not writing to a file in raw directory but to a file on the file system.

Comment: Conclusion: you do not need an empty file in raw directory to begin with.

Comment: So how can I export my data to any arbitrary file whose location is given by me?

Comment: You are already doing that. So what is the exact problem? Your code should work be it that it will not be in csv format. Tell more about 'the location'. You now store the file in the location given by getFilesDir().

Comment: The problem is that It needs to write to a csv file in defined structure. And after the writing I cannot find the file.

Comment: getFilesDir() is private internal memory for your app. No other app has acces. You did not tell though how you tried to find the file. But you can read the file with openFileInput().

Comment: `It needs to write to a csv file in defined structure`. I suppose so. And that is all info we get?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to Android so I am not getting what you said. How should I modify the current code?

Comment: You did not answer my question. So why should i help you further?

Comment: Sorry I did not see it. So it should write the list in such structure:

Column A           Column B
List[0],String[0]    List[0].String[1]
List[1],String[0]    List[0].String[1]
List[2],String[0]    List[0].String[1]
.
.
.
and so on.

Comment: Repeat: `You did not tell though how you tried to find the file.`

Comment: `So it should write the list in such structure` In which stucture? You still did not tell how it should be.

Comment: I edited the question above so you can see the structure